# Extract value of the key from a map basis on a priority?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, lookup

I have a map of String and String. I want to extract key value and assign it to another String variable but in a priority order.

- If `abc` key is present, then assign value of `abc` to `clientId` variable and we are done.
- Buf if `abc` key is not present, then look for this key `pqr` and assign value of `pqr` to `clientId` variable and we are done.
- But if `pqr` key is also not present, then look for this key `def` and assign value of `def` to `clientId` variable and we are done.
- But if none of those keys are present, then value of `clientId` will be null.

Below is the code:

```
Map<String, String> holderMap = populateHolderMap<>();
String clientId = null;

if (!holderMap.isEmpty()) {
  clientId = holderMap.get("abc");
  if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(clientId)) {
    clientId = holderMap.get("pqr");
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(clientId)) {
      clientId = holderMap.get("def");
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any better way to write this thing? Or may be one liner using ternary operator?

There is a possibility that all three keys can be present or two keys can be present and I always have to stick to my order only. If `abc` key is present, then we will use that no matter whether other keys are presents or not.

Comment: `if ((clientId = holderMap.get("abc")) == null || (clientId = holderMap.get("pqr")) || (clientId = holderMap.get("def"))) {clientId = null;}`

Comment: If we have to use ternary operator how it can be done in one line?

Comment: There is a possibility that all three keys can be present but I need to stick to my order only. If abc is present, then we will use that no matter whether other are present or not.

Comment: using `||` will shortcut the selection process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go for code readability over lesser lines of code. what you have is fine.

Using ternary operator: 
The syntax is condition ? if_condition_true : if_condition_false;

```
if (!holderMap.isEmpty()) {
  clientId = holderMap.get("abc") == null ? 
             holderMap.get("pqr") == null ? 
             holderMap.get("def") == null ? 
             null : holderMap.get("def") : holderMap.get("pqr") : holderMap.get("abc");
}
```

Using if and else if

```
if (!holderMap.isEmpty()) {
    if( holderMap.get("abc") != null ) {
       clientId = holderMap.get("abc");
    } else if ( holderMap.get("pqr") != null ) {
       clientId = holderMap.get("pqr");
    } else if (holderMap.get("def") != null ) {
       clientId = holderMap.get("def");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am open for both. I wanted to see how we can write in  a better way using normal if/else condition vs how we will write it with ternary operator.

Comment: @user5447339 what scary-wombat has in comment is also a way to do it. even els if would be fine.